# How to use variable to select database in Pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, database-connection, pymongo

Usually I connect to a database in Pymongo like this:

```
    # connect to the MongoDB
    connection = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")

    # connect to the database
    self.db = self.connection.my_database
```

The problem is, the name of `my_database` always changes. How can I use a variable to choose the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-database) we can do it like this:

```
# connect to the MongoDB
connection = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")

# connect to the database
a = 'my_database'
self.db = self.connection[a]
```

Comment: What is "self" referring to in this example?

Comment: @NealWalters a custom class I made. Since I build it inside a class